# How can I edit an Excel sheet using C code?

Tags: c, excel, import-from-excel

I have an existing Excel with Sheet Sheet1 which has 3 Columns:
e.g. FeatureName FeatureLabel FeatureDesc

I have 5 rows with the respective data.

I want to open the Excel and add a new row in the Excel using **C** code.

Can anyone suggest me a solution for the same?

Comment: Saved in what format ?

Comment: The excel is in .xlsx format and need to modify and save it in the same format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [libxlsxwriter](https://libxlsxwriter.github.io/index.html) to write text, numbers, formulas and hyperlinks to multiple worksheets in an Excel 2007+ XLSX file.

This [tutorial](https://libxlsxwriter.github.io/tutorial01.html) can help you to add new row by using `worksheet_write` family function (for example, `worksheet_write_number`, `worksheet_write_string`, `worksheet_write_formula`).

Comment: What if I want to edit an exisitng excel file? Can I still use libxlsxwriter?

Comment: i don't know, try to use `workbook_new` with the exist filename, maybe it can open it. You can also use `libxls` library (http://libxls.sourceforge.net/) to read the xlsx file then copy all info in original file to new file before adding new row. You can also use  the C standard functions , for example `fopen` and `fwrite`, etc if your excel file is not complicate

Comment: it's all things i can help you. Execl file is complicate format with C, you can use another language, for example Python, C sharp, etc to handle it